# Google Places API: supported types for tram/cable car/light-rail?

Tags: web-services, google-maps, google-places-api

I'm taking my first steps at using [Google Places API](https://developers.google.com/places/) am currently experimenting with [different types](https://developers.google.com/places/supported_types). I was wondering, what kind of type I have to use, if I want to search for tram/cable car/light-rails stations?

What I want is get a list of subway, bus and tram stations inside an defined radius for an arbitrary coordinate.

Subway and bus seem to be easy (`types=subway_station` or `types=bus_station`) but there does not seem to be an equivalent for trams.

Just for experimenting:

Search for the tram station "Agnes-Bernauer-Platz" at Munich (coordinates: 48.1398418,11.496119, good example because there are not subway or bus stations in direct vicinity.) If you interactively browse Google Maps, the station is found (with a "tram icon"), but Places API does not find it:

```
https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/place/nearbysearch/xml?location=48.1398418,11.496119&radius=100&key=....
```

Any ideas?
Thanks in advance!

**Update:**

```
types=light_rail_station
```

Comment: Please post that as an answer to your question.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Ok, it seems there *is* already a type which is not yet documented at [developers.google.com/places/supported_types](http://developers.google.com/places/supported_types): `types=light_rail_station` does the job.

Comment: I raised a bug report to fix this issue here: https://issuetracker.google.com/36824755

Comment: I have similar problem, 'light_rail_station' is not documented in developers.google.com/places/supported_types but is huge used for example in "Milan, Italy"